# Even neighbors in a vertex subset

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of odd order. Prove that there exists a non-empty vertex subset $U$ of $G$ such that each vertex in $G$ has an even number of neighbors in $U$.

[image]

Here are all the graphs on five vertices that are neither disconnected nor trees which are either trivial or not very difficult to find.  (There are likely some mistakes, for instance $G_{16}$ should also have its top vertex shaded.) There is no discernable pattern that I can spot.  Sometimes it is all of the vertices with even degree, sometimes it is all of the vertices with odd degree, and sometimes neither of those work.

An induction proof is theoretically possible.  If the graph is empty, then the solution is trivial.  Otherwise we could take some edge $uv$ and consider the graph induced by the vertex set $V\setminus\{u,v\}$.  That would have a solution by our induction hypothesis. But how that could be transformed to a solution for $G$ is not intuitively obvious.

Comment: Induction seems like a good place to start.

Comment: @DavidNehme if we let U be the vertices of the $K_3$

Comment: I find this question extremely interesting! may I ask where it is taken from?

Comment: Very similar (but not quite identical to) [USAMO 2008/6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2008_USAMO_Problems/Problem_6).

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I’m reading an article about equiangular lines. De Caen gave a construction in 1999.

Answer (score 8):

Let $n$ be the (odd) order of $G$ and $A$ the adjacency matrix associated to $G$. You seek a nonzero solution to $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. It suffices to show that the determinant of $A$ is even.

Let $S = (\epsilon_{i,j} a_{i,j})_{1 \le i,j \le n}$, where $\epsilon_{i,j} = -1$ if $i < j$ and $\epsilon_{i,j} = 1$ otherwise. Then $\det(S) = \det(S^T) = \det(-S) = (-1)^n\det(S) = -\det(S)$, so $\det(S) = 0$.

Finally, observe that $S = A$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so $0 \equiv \det(S) \equiv \det(A) \pmod{2}$, as desired.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @User2020201 he has predicted numerous important events. he has access to a lot of private information.

Comment: What are his prediction about lasting it?

Comment: @User2020201 I'm not sure actually. I'll get back to you.