# Graphs with no vertices of even degree

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, in which every vertex has odd degree. The Handshaking Lemma implies that $n$ is even. Also, if $G$ is disconnected, then it is the disjoint union of smaller graphs with odd degrees only, so wlog. assume that $G$ is connected.

I'm just wondering if there is anything else that can be said about such $G$ in general? Are there any theorems that expose some sort of restrictions on the structure of $G$? Or any noteworthy sufficient conditions on a graph to contain an even degree vertex?

Comment: not an answer, but you might find this interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508237/even-neighbors-in-a-vertex-subset/3511329#3511329

Comment: Such graphs can be either very sparse or very dense. Indeed, you can take a suitable star graph or a complete graph to see this. In fact, I don't believe a structural characterization is simple to give.

There's also a well-known result saying that a connected graph has an Eulerian cycle precisely when each vertex has even degree. Further, by Veblen's theorem, a graph can be decomposed into edge-disjoint cycles precisely when all of its vertices have even degree. In other words, it follows that odd graphs never have an Eulerian cycle and never admit a partition into edge-disjoint cycles.

Comment: @mrm it follows that a disconnected graph with all degrees odd is the complement of an Eulerian graph.  In general, a graph has all degrees odd if and only if its complement can be partitioned into edge-disjoint cycles.